# SQL : Find if XML node exists

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sqlxml

Assuming I have a table data as below:[image: Sample Table]

I want to Select all `Value`(XML Data) which contains the node `Name="Hello World"`. How can I achieve it?

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ce0fe/1)

```
set @f = @XML.exist('/ArrayOfFilterColumn/SelectColumn[(@Name) eq "Hello World"]');
select @f;
```

I am not sure how could I add it in my where condition, so I have put it in a fiddle.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Skip the use of an XML variable and put the exist in the where clause when you query the table.

```
select F.Value
from XML_FILES as F
where F.Value.exist('/ArrayOfArrayOfSelectColumn/SelectColumn[@Name eq "Hello World"]') = 1
```

Your column is apparently `text` so you need to change that because `text` is deprecated and has been for quite some time.

[ntext, text, and image (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187993(v=sql.120).aspx)

> ntext , text, and image data types will be removed in a future version
>   of Microsoft SQL Server. Avoid using these data types in new
>   development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use
>   them. Use nvarchar(max), varchar(max), and varbinary(max) instead.

In your case you should of course change to XML instead.

Until you fix that you can cast to XML in your query.

```
select F.Value
from XML_FILES as F
where cast(F.Value as xml).exist('/ArrayOfArrayOfSelectColumn/SelectColumn[@Name eq "Hello World"]') = 1
```

Comment: My column Value is of type `text`. So it is returning me an error as `Cannot call methods on text.` My mistake as in my fiddle I have mentioned it as type `XML`

Comment: @Gun.IO You fooled me by using a XML column in the fiddle.

Comment: My mistake. Apologies!

Comment: For Posterity - Mikael's answer is correct. However I did want to mention that you shouldn't get confused by the '.Value' part of the answer, as the XML function .value is NOT what's being called here. Instead, the name of the column where we're checking for existence of a node is called 'Value'.